# How to get a list of all columns after a JOIN?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have several `JOIN` in a `SELECT` that effectively generate a long list of columns.

```sql
SELECT * FROM db1 db1
JOIN db2 db2 ON db1.id=db2.id
JOIN db3 db3 ON db1.id=db3.id
(...)
```

Is there a way to list the names of all resulting columns, ideally in the form `table_name.column_name`? (something along the lines of `DESCRIBE` for a table)

Comment: I agree. I see nothing wrong with the question although I can't answer to it. +1

Comment: @WoJ, not exactly what you want, but something like this can be done.
```CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT ....``` all your joins, and then ```DESC tmp```. This will describe all the columns with assumed types, etc.

Comment: I know how you might do this in MS SQL Server which provides some system views for referenced object dependencies which you would then join to the sys.tables view and from there sys.columns - presumably the same functionality exists in MySql somehere unfortunately I don't know the product that well.

Comment: Perhaps the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` might give you what you need?

Comment: @RobEyre, output of `EXPLAIN` won't give something similar to `DESC`. It would just show how that query will be executed, which tables, which keys, how many rows scanned, etc.  Not the columns and type of columns of the output.

Comment: Bold to assume it's always possible to describe a query column using `table.column` syntax. A query could have literal columns, columns constructed from several tables, case expressions, function calls, etc. But maybe `LIMIT 0` would help.